# iwlist failed to read scan data : network is down

Tags: networking, wireless, interface

I need to use my phone to write this since wifi on my Ubuntu labtop no longer functions. I'm using release 18.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad. Kernel version is 4.15.0-23-generic. 
I started having problems after using Bluetooth to connect to a Bose speaker. After watching a podcast for a while I found that I could no longer use wifi. I shut off Bluetooth and rebooted, but this did not help. Tried ifup but the interface from iwlist (wlp5s0) is unknown.

After some searching and finding that suggested commands are not installed by default (e.g. ifconfig) or do not help (ip link set wlp5s0) I'm hoping for answers here.

Comment: Got exactly the same issue with my x230 with Kernel 4.15.0-43

Comment: I just found for myself, that I accidentally switched off the wifi using the analog wifi switch on the left side of my Notebook.